# Prompt for terraform variable only once

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform script that creates a route 53 entry for a NLB that I may have created through some other process.
I have a variable to read in the ARN of the NLB, and if I pass empty string, the route 53 entry is not created/deleted. This is all good, but I am manually passing the ARN of the NLB into Terraform as a variable, and it's quite annoying and error-prone having to do this each time I run `terraform apply` to update some other resource. Is there a better way to do this, in a way that I don't have to re-enter the NLB ARN after the route 53 entry is created?

Comment: There's probably a few ways around this but I think this is going to cause you issues. Either Terraform should be managing a resource or not at all (potentially just resolving its attributes via a data source). Trying to handle it conditionally being there is likely to cause you a lot of pain. If this is a one off thing then you should consider importing the resource so Terraform can manage it. If this is a longer ongoing thing then it might help to edit your question to explain what you are doing that requires Terraform to occasionally manage a resource but not always.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Well, terraform is managing the route 53 entry, when it exists, but not what it points to. I would like to only create it when I pass non empty string, but after it's created, I no longer want to be prompted for the "what it points to" variable, if that makes sense.

Comment: What's the point of having Terraform manage the record at all in that case? And have you considered using the `ignore_changes` lifecycle configuration to have Terraform manage the existence of the record but not what it points to?

Comment: The point to have terraform manage it, is that I want it to be cleaned up when I am done. The trouble is that I can't query a NLB by tags, I must specify a name/arn. However I can't control either, and it's different every time. (This deployment will be made on many different accounts).